selenium Webscrapping Dates from oddsportal
I cant find elegant way to get the dates of the matches along with odds:
Lets say here is my url: 'https://www.oddsportal.com/football/usa/mls/'
I can get all the matches with:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Load the webpage
    driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/football/usa/mls/')

    # Give the page time to load
    sleep(3)

    # Scroll to the bottom of the page to load all content
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    sleep(3)  # Wait for content to load

    # Extract all date elements
    date_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                         '//div[@class="text-black-main font-main w-full truncate text-xs font-normal leading-5"]')
    dates = [date_element.text.strip() for date_element in date_elements]

    # Extract all game rows
    game_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="group flex"]')
    rowData = [row.text.split("\n") for row in game_rows]

    matches = []

    # Iterate over game rows
    for i in range(len(rowData)):
        try:
            if len(rowData[i]) == 10:
                time = rowData[i][0]
                Home = rowData[i][1]
                Away = rowData[i][5]
                odds_1 = rowData[i][6]
                odds_X = rowData[i][7]
                odds_2 = rowData[i][8]
                Final_result = rowData[i][2] + ":" + rowData[i][4]
            elif len(rowData[i]) == 8:
                time = rowData[i][0]
                Home = rowData[i][1]
                Away = rowData[i][3]
                odds_1 = rowData[i][4]
                odds_X = rowData[i][5]
                odds_2 = rowData[i][6]
                Final_result = ":"
            else:
                continue  # Skip if it doesn't match the expected length

            # Append the row data
            matches.append([time, Home, Away, odds_1, odds_X, odds_2, Final_result])
        except IndexError:
            print(f"Skipping row {i} due to insufficient data")

    # Convert to DataFrame for better visualization
    df = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Time', 'Home', 'Away', '1', 'X', '2', 'Final result'])

I can also get all dates with
    date_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                         '//div[@class="text-black-main font-main w-full truncate text-xs font-normal leading-5"]')
    dates = [date_element.text.strip() for date_element in date_elements]

number of elements in dataframe and in list dates is different.
I tried some workaround with match time but it doesn't work as the match can start at the same time in different days.
Potentially i can go to each and every match and extract date from there but it is too time consuming.
Any advice?
